# Most efficient way to parse in a large range in to an array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, matrix

I have a large range of data in excel that I would like to parse into an array for a user defined function. The range is 2250 x 2250. It takes far too long to parse each cell in via a for loop, and it is too large to be assigned to an array via this method:

```
dim myArr as Variant
myArr = range("myrange")
```

Just brainstorming here, would it be more efficient to parse in each column and join the arrays? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I just setup a workbook with data in range a1 to chn2250 (a range of 2250X2250) and read it into a variant array called "x" using `x= range("a1:chn2250").Value2` then just to ensure it worked did `debug.print x(2,2)`. The whole operation took less than a second. So, I would suggest a variant array.

Comment: Try adding the `.Value` or `.Value2` as @Kyle suggested to what you had above.

Comment: I didn't explicitly state the `.Value2`, but that is a performance enhancer for sure.

Comment: `2250×2250×(8 bytes per double) = 38.6 Mb` which should not stress the memory at all.

Comment: @ja72 how do you know that they are doubles?  what if they're all 1024 length strings?  It's a Variant Array...Variant variables with numbers require 16 bytes of memory.  Variables of the Variant data type with characters usually require 22 bytes of memory plus the memory required by the string.  This doesn't even talk about the memory used for the array structure itself.

Comment: @Daniel was trying to copy over 5,000,000 cells.  That's a lot of data.  I tried it with 4,500,000 and ran into the same problem (w/16GB RAM).  Once Excel crashed, and I was forced to start again (without 8 other workbooks open) it worked fine without the error.

Answer (score 4):

You're nearly there.

The code you need is:

```
Dim myArr as Variant
myArr = range("myrange").Value2
```

Note that I'm using the `.Value2` property of the range, not just 'Value', which reads formats and locale settings, and will probably mangle any dates

Note, also, that I haven't bothered to `Redim` and specify the dimensions of the array: the Value and Value2 properties are a 2-dimensional array, (1 to Rowcount, 1 to Col Count)...  Unless it's a single cell, which will be a scalar variant which breaks any downstream code that expected an array. But that's not your problem with a known 2250 x 2250 range.

If you reverse the operation, and write an array back to a range, you will need to set the size of the receiving range *exactly* to the dimensions of the array. Again, not your problem with the question you asked: but the two operations generally go together.

The general principle is that each 'hit' to the worksheet takes about a twentieth of a second - some machines are much faster, but they all have bad days - and the 'hit' or reading a single cell to a variable is almost exactly the same as reading a seven-million-cell range into a variant array. Both are several **million** times faster than reading that range in one cell at a time.

Either way, you may as well count any operation in VBA as happening in zero time once you've done the 'read-in' and stopped interacting with the worksheet.

The numbers are all very rough-and-ready, but the general principles will hold, right up until the moment you start allocating arrays that won't fit in the working memory and, again, that's not your problem today.

Remember to `Erase` the array variant when you've finished, rather than relying on it going out of scope: that'll  make a difference, with a range this size.

Comment: Hi Nile, Thank you so much for the detailed explination. I had not thought to use Value2, and it seems like it should work. However, I may be running into the memory capacity. The macro is now breaking saying that it is out of memory. The size of the sheet is 70k kb since each cell in the matrix has a function. Is there any other recommendations you can make for me? If not I can try and delete some redundant information.

Comment: @Daniel  - Is the macro breaking on the `arr = Range.Value2` statement? There's a limit to what you can do, but declaring a range object variable and using that may help; as will setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: @Daniel - if those steps don't solve the problem, your next step is to redim the array manually, then pass the range value into it: `Redim arr(1 to rng.Rows.Count, 1 to rng.Columns.Count`  and then try `arr = rng.Value2`   ...And the step after *that* is to load the range in chunks - either a thousand rows or a thousand or columns at a time.                           Also: you *are* using `Option.Explicit` or the 'Require Variable Declaration' option in VBA?

Comment: @NigelHeffernan while adding `.Value2` looks like it speeds the code up by about **10%**...it does nothing to address the OP.  FYI using `.Formula` took about 2x as long (with my data set), which makes sense, since strings are larger.

Comment: @Profex - Value2 is (or should be) the first thing you try when reading the values in a range; everything else will encumber you with dependencies on local formats . The canonical example is using .Value2 to retrieve the underlying date serial.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine.

```
Sub T()
    Dim A() As Variant

    A = Range("A2").Resize(2250, 2250).Value2

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To 2250
        For j = 1 To 2250
            If i = j Then A(i, j) = 1
        Next j
    Next i

    Range("A2").Resize(2250, 2250).Value2 = A
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting trick!  ...Can you check if declaring a Range variable, setting it to the monster range, and populating the array from this Range variable works, too? This error may be machine-dependent, but the proximate cause is that VBA makes wild guesses about the memory it needs to allocate when it tries to interpret `Range( [some string we'll parse at runtime] ).Value2` instead of a well-behaved object with a VTable, or (as you've shown us) a range-returning function with a clearly-defined size.

Comment: Like `Set r = Range("..").Resize(..)` and then `vals = r.Values2`? This is the same as above.

Comment: - Not quite. In terms of what the code is *intended* to do, both approaches are the same. But is the compiler (and the runtime behaviour) smart enough to recognise that your range object r has known dimensions at compile-time? Or is the implementation for reading the dimensions of a range variable different (less likely to make wild guesses and overestimates when allocating memory) to the mechanism for reading it out of a Range method with an arbitrary address string?

Comment: I would guess that the array in `arr = Range("A1").Value` is being allocated before the address string is parsed - possibly to the dimensions of the entire worksheet! - and then redimensioned when the row and col counts are known. But a declared range object has no `.Value` property to pass to an array variant until the dimensions are known, and the runtime engine has to perform the tasks in the correct sequence It is, of course, entirely possible that the error message isn't really *'Out of Memory'*: it might be "Oops! I need to allocate memory **right now** but one of the numbers is missing"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler knows what size the range is...it doesn't make a difference just because it's explicitly spelled out for us humans to read.  It's not guessing at the size or trying to allocate any memory until it gets to that line....that's the way VBA works AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best options are:

1. Try to limit the data to a reasonable number, say 1,000,000 values at a time.
2. Add some error handling to catch the `Out of Memory` error and then try again, but cut the size in half, then by a third, a quarter, etc...until it works.

Either way, if we're using data sets in the order of 5,000,000 values and you want to make sure that the program will run, you will need to adjust the code to chop up the data.